# Xerox WorkCentre 3615 driver issue

Tags: drivers, printing, xerox

We just received a `WorkCenter 3615` printer in the Lab and I'm trying to use in the local network under `Ubuntu 14.04`.

I am not totally sure that the problem is with the driver (but it is the most probable)

I found the printer in the list of `Network Printers` and I downloaded and installed (with Ubuntu Software Center) the driver `Linux Intel Driver .DEB x86_64` from the official [page](http://www.support.xerox.com/support/workcentre-3615/downloads/engb.html?operatingSystem=linux&fileLanguage=en_GB). In the new printer setup process, phase **Choose Driver**, the online search fails and if I choose **Select printer from database**, then the recommended is an other one (**X. WC. 3119**) and there is no driver for our printer **3615**. I tried this driver, but when I print the test page, prints on a lot of pages strange characters.

I can't find online any `ppd` file for this printer, in the windows drivers there is only one zip file and it is just for the scanner and does not contain the `ppd`.

Am I doing something wrong with the installation? 
Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'v read that the official driver and ppd file is broken, but I found a working **PPD** at [this page](https://seeit.org/2015/11/17/xerox-workcentre-3615dn-printer-ppd-file/).

I added the printer and set the driver through ppt file from the source above and it worked.